# MySQL как сделать update с вложенным запросом?

Tags: mysql, update

**Задача:** Уменьшить цены книг на 20 процентов того автора, суммарная стоимость всех экземпляров книг которого максимальна (не стоимость всех книг на складе, а стоимость всех уникальных книг автора ).

таблица book выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я пытался сделать:

UPDATE book
SET price = price * 0.8
WHERE book.author_id =
(SELECT author_id
FROM book
GROUP BY author_id
HAVING SUM(price) >= ALL(SELECT SUM(price) FROM book GROUP BY author_id));

но этот запрос выдает ошибку: ERROR 1093: You can't specify target table 'book' for update in FROM clause

Как переписать запрос?

Comment: Изучите multiple-table UPDATE syntax. PS. И не используйте ALL и остальные предикаты, пока не поймёте, как именно они работают.

Comment: можете написать правильный код этой задачи я не пониммаю как вообще ее решать?

Comment: На самом деле задача недоопределена, а в нынешней формулировке - просто-таки противоречива. Достаточно добавить в таблицу ещё одну, уже имеющуюся там, книгу, но с другой ценой - и ты не будешь знать, что делать и какую из двух цен брать.

Comment: не надо ничего добавлять. все ясно. я даже знаю у какого автора суммарная цена максимальная - это автор с id = 2. И у этого автора нужно цены книг уменьшить на 20%. Конечно я могу сделать это тупо указав id в условии where, но это ручная работа. Есть ли запрос, который определяет авторов с максимальной суммарной стоимостью книг и на основе этих данных делает update цены книг для этих авторов ? просто update не умеет обновлять таблицу, если во вложенном запросе используется эта таблица, а другого способа я не знаю. может join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE book
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT author_id
               FROM book
               GROUP BY 1
               ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC LIMIT 1 ) expensive 
SET price = price * 0.8;
```

И будь готов ответить преподавателю на вопрос "как изменится запрос, если добавить ещё одну запись ..." (в общем, то, на что я указал в комментарии).

Comment: спасибо, самое интересное, что через join я тоже пытался делать, код был почти такой же, но забыл прописать условие ON , зато теперь я знаю что есть NATURAL JOIN. А преподавателя у меня нет. Я учусь по задачам из интернета

Comment: @Midsummer1 Ну вот теперь усложни задачу, представь, что одна и та же книга может присутствовать несколько раз, и тогда надо брать минимальную (или максимальную) из её цен... очень хорошая задачка для самообразования.